# accessing array values returns 'undefined', but I can see the values with console.dir()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

EDIT: here is a full gist of my code (API key of course removed): https://gist.github.com/tconroy/e52e0e7402face8f048e

I am having some issues with accessing `objects{}` stored inside a JavaScript `array[]`.

When I do `console.dir(containerArray)`, I can see the 2 objects stored inside the array, like in the photo below:

[image]

However, when I perform

`console.log(containerArray)`,

the output is just empty brackets `[]`.

When I try and access the array indexes via `console.dir(containerArray[0]);`, the output is `undefined`.

This is the code I am using to create the objects and put them into the array:

```
var key  = String(decodeURIComponent(addr)),
obj  = {};
obj[key] = json.data.weather;
containerArray.push(obj);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I need to be able to access each of the objects stored in the array and not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Pls put the code & output here, not as picture

Comment: I have a suspicion, but please show how you are creating this `containerArray`.

Comment: I have added the code for how I am creating the objects. containerArray is just created like this: `var containerArray = [];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the `json.data` object, I'm going to take a shot in the dark.

You are loading `containerArray`'s data in some kind of AJAX callback, but trying to access it outside of said callback.

Example:

```
MyAJAXFunction("url", function(json) {
    containerArray.push(json.data.weather);
});
alert(containerArray[0]); // why undefined?
```

The reason it seems to work with `console.dir` can be seen by hovering over that little <kbd>i</kbd> icon: It has a *reference* to the object, which was updated before you browsed it.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm doing -- how do I pass the actual object into the array instead of just a reference? Does the json.data.weather no longer exist outside of the callback, even though I'm pushing it to array?

Comment: Anything that uses the result of a callback, MUST itself be in the callback, called by the callback, or otherwise deferred until after the callback has completed.

Comment: So I cannot retrieve the data in the callback, store it in a global var, and access it outside of the callback? All of my processing code needs to exist inside the callback? That seems really messy and tedious :/

Comment: my issue is I'm actually looping through inputs, doing AJAX call with each input, and I want to store the JSON results for formatting into a graph in a later function, so I want to send all the data at once so the graph is created at the same time with all needed data.

Comment: "called by the callback" may be your best option. Call `dataReady()` or something to do your actual code.

Comment: yes but how do I make sure I have data from all my ajax calls before calling `dataReady()`? I don't want to perform actions on each response individually, but rather as a group.